# How to use NavigationCardStack's direction prop properly

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to use `NavigationCardStack`'s `direction` prop properly? (RN v0.30.0)
I'm setting the prop currently via

```
const direction = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index].direction || 'horizontal';
```

It works when navigating forward, however when navigating backward, it's always the current active scene's direction instead of the previous scene

Answer (score 0):

The `NavigationCardStack` does not support setting the direction for every card in the stack.

A pull request has been made [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/9257).